# openssl verify signature

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, digital-signature

For S/MIME, I now know I can verify PKCS#7 detached signatures with:

```
openssl smime -verify -in detachedsign.pem -content content.txt
```

But what about non-MIME messages?
So if I sign the message `Hello, World!` with `openssl smime -sign -text....` it will actually be signing

```
Content-Type: plain/text

Hello, World!
```

Is it possible to use *openssl* to sign a normal text file (as it is)? When `-sign` outputs a PKCS#7 detached signature and `-verify` accepts a PKCS#7 detached signature and content

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use OpenSSL to create and sign a message digest of the plain text file and later use that signed digest to confirm the validity of the text.

> openssl sha1 -sign rsaprivate.pem -out rsasign.bin file.txt

and later verify the validity of the text message using

> openssl sha1 -verify rsapublic.pem -signature rsasign.bin file.txt

Check out the O'Reilly book *Network Security with OpenSSL* for a good documentation source for these functions.  The example above came from that book.

Comment: Thanks Zedman, but I meant signing into a PKCS#7 object just like smime option does (and verifying from a PKCS#7 public key certificate as well). I'll add this to the question to become more explicit.

Comment: One other question, on pure terminology, you say "sign a message digest", but it is "encrypt message digest" or "sign message" right? As signing is basically encrypting an hash, as far I as understand.

Comment: @Filipe by 'sign a message digest’ I mean encrypt a message digest (with the author's private key) which is how a message is signed using PKI.  Sorry if I confused the issue.   The message itself can also be encrypted but that is a different subject.  By definition, the public key certificate is checked for trust since that is the foundation requirement of PKI functionality.  The syntax of the example commands should work for any keypair OpenSSL supports.

Comment: Right, so you agree with what I said in previous comment: it's not "sign message digest" as you used in your answer, it's just "sign message" as "sign message digest" would imply "encrypt digest of message digest" :) anyway, the above commands do not output PKCS7 objects, just plain signature. I was hoping command line openssl tool would be able to the PKCS7_sign that the (openssl) library provides http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS7_sign.html but it seems it can't...

Comment: The book I referenced provides a way to do that programmatically but nothing for the command line so it appears you are correct.

Comment: Very late now, but in case anyone searches: `openssl smime` **does support plain CMS signing and enveloping** in either DER (standard) or PEM (semistandard) format as well as S/MIME. Specify `-outform der|pem` to create and `-inform der|pem` to read (actually just `d` or `p` is enough). For signature detached is the default, but you can specify `-nodetach` for embedded.

Answer (score 1):

According to [qistoph's blog](https://qistoph.blogspot.com/2013/04/pkcs7-and-openssl.html) (and dave_thompson_085's comment), to sign a message

```
openssl smime -sign -nodetach -inkey keyfile.key -signer cert.cer -in unsigned.txt -inform pem -out signed.p7m
```

Where `unsigned.txt` is the file to sign; `keyfile.key` is a PKCS#8 private key (not encrypted); `cert.cer` is an X.509 certificate. `signed.p7s` will be an attached PKCS#7 signature, meaning that the payload (`unsigned.txt`) is included in the signature. To get detached signature, remove the flag `-nodetach` (and name the output file with extension `.p7s`, according to [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551#section-3.10)).

To verify the signature:

```
openssl smime -verify -in signed.p7 -inform pem
```

If the certificate itself don’t need to be verified (for example, when it isn’t signed by public CA), add a `-noverify` flag. `-noverify` only disables certificate verification; payload signature is still verified.

Comment: You forgot `-outform p[em]` on sign

Comment: Looks to me like OP already knows about `smime` and doesn't want that. He also wants a detached signature.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald I re-read the question, and found that OP was confused about different things than I was. My question was “how do I create (sign) and verify a PKCS#7”. Shall I create another (self-answering) question about it? I searched a while in this site and found no other question about it.